# Integers that can be expressed as a sum of two integer exponentials

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It is well known that an integer can be expressed as a sum of two squares iff all of it's $4k+3$ prime divisors have a even degree in it's prime factorization.
As a result of some googling, I've also found that also it's not beautiful as the case of squares, there also exists a condition of $n$ equivalent with $n$ being expressed as a sum of two cubes.
(http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/JIS/VOL6/Broughan/broughan25.pdf)

So naturally, now what I'm wondering is, is there any conditions known about numbers that can be  expressed by $x^n +y^n$, where $n \ge 4$ is some given integer,  and $x,y$ are arbitrary integers?

Comment: Right off, you know if $n$ is even, then it reduces to a special case of the sum of two squares.

Comment: hmm... does anyone know something more?